# Scrapy twisted. Web error

Tags: scrapy

```
twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived:
<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record', 'wrong version number')]>
```

I'm going to run scrapy and get this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved it, because I started the VPN, and I'll just close it

Answer (score 1):

I guess that Scrapy's downloader can't agree on SSL version to use during negotiation with the server. Try to set [`DOWNLOADER_CLIENT_TLS_METHOD`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#downloader-client-tls-method) in your `settings.py` to `'SSLv3'` value and if that doesn't help, try to set it to `'TLSv1.0'`.

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it, because I've used a VPN, so there's a bug that has never been seen before